# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused Laravel 5.6 and Laradock

Tags: laravel, laradock

I have a problem with my database mysql. I can not access it, I have a laravel project which I added Laradock to be able to use the containers with Docker. I launched two containers typing docker-compose up -d mysql nginx in my laradock directory. Once the containers are launched, I can access Laravel's home page, but when I want to communicate with my database  I have the following error:

> SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] Connection refused.

Someone has an idea of ​​the source of my problem. Thank you .

```
i am on ubuntu 17.10 

Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
```

my .env file in project is here

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_authors
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

.env file on laradock folder is

```
MYSQL_VERSION=8.0
MYSQL_DATABASE=db_authors
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB=./mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

and here is mysql container in my docker-compose.yml

```
mysql:
  build:
    context: ./mysql
    args:
      - MYSQL_VERSION=${MYSQL_VERSION}
  environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
  volumes:
    - ${DATA_SAVE_PATH}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    - ${MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  ports:
    - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
  networks:
    - backend
```

my containers are well launched here is the result I get by doing

```
docker-compose up -d mysql nginx


Creating network "laradock_default" with the default driver
Creating laradock_mysql_1        ... done
Creating network "laradock_backend" with driver "bridge"
Creating laradock_workspace_1    ... done
Creating laradock_applications_1 ... 
Creating laradock_php-fpm_1      ... done
Creating laradock_php-fpm_1      ... 
Creating laradock_nginx_1        ... do
```

Comment: Post entire `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: my docker-composer file, it's the same as laradock's, it's long I just modified the myql @Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:
1 - Enter the MySQL container: docker-compose exec mysql bash.
2 - Enter mysql: mysql -uroot -proot
3 - See all users: SELECT User FROM mysql.user;
4 - Run any commands show databases, show tables, select * from......

Does it work? Can you log on MySQL like that?